# How can I create an interval in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I found this option here, but it does it in a new thread that the android doesn’t like when I use **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

```java
        final Timer time = new Timer();

        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    if(Objects.equals(check, "Подключение установлено ✅")) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        time.cancel();
                    }
            }
        }, 2000, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't touch the views on background threads. You must do it on the UI thread. 
Use the postDelayed method to run on the UI thread. The runnable in postDelayed  will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something here after 2000ms
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This calls the **run** function only once. I need to repeat the function once per **n** amount of time

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //your code here...
            }
        }),2000;
```